# Overloading templated class method

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance

I try to overload a protected function of one of my XML class.

In short, there are the `C_XmlArrayField<T>` which help saving `std::list<T>` objects, with primitive type (or type with a `operator>>` with `std::*stringstream`). And I've got `C_XmlClassArrayField<T>` which do the same thing, but with class inheriting for the `C_XmlBasicObject` class (which is an abstract class with two method, one for saving the instance into a XML element, and another for loading the instance from an XML element).

So, the `C_XmlArrayField<T>` have the writing and reading function, and a `writeItem` and a `readItem` virtual function, which use `std::*stringstream` for writing/reading a single item. The `C_XmlClassArrayField<T>` is declared in this way :

```
template<T>
class C_XmlClassArrayField : public C_XmlArrayField<T*>
{ ... blabla ... }
```

I give you the two files :

- For the `C_XmlArrayField<T>` : http://pastebin.com/Mtfs3ShC
- For the `C_XmlClassArrayField<T>` : http://pastebin.com/PFKFq0RK

So, this is my problem :

I overloaded the `writeItem` and the `readItem` for `C_XmlClassArrayField<T>` but, this give me an error when I try to use is with a testing class (which inherit from `C_XmlBasicObject`) :

```
Libraries/ns_framework/Headers/ns/xml/C_XmlArrayField.hpp:203:7: error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istringstream {aka std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char>}' and 'Test*')
```

I don't understand because I overloaded the virtual function within `C_XmlClassArrayField<T>`.

Finally, my test code :

```
#include <iostream>

#include <ns/xml.hpp>
#include <ns/scene.hpp>
#include <ns/anim.hpp>
#include <ns/utils.hpp>


using namespace std;
using namespace ns;
using namespace tinyxml2;


// C_XmlObject inherits from C_XmlBasicObject.
class Test : public C_XmlObject
{
public:
    Test(string name="test") :
        C_XmlObject(name)
    {
        addField<int>("int").set(42);
    }
};



int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{

    C_XmlClassArrayField<Test> array("test");

    array->push_back(new Test());
    array->push_back(new Test());


    XMLDocument doc;
    auto root = doc.NewElement("root");
    doc.InsertFirstChild(root);

    array.write(doc, root);

    doc.Print();

    return 0;
}
```

Did I miss something with the templates ?

Thanks for your answers !

**Edit 1** : @r-sahu says I need to overload the `operator >>`, but this isn't what I search. I want to know how I can get ride of this error with overloading the `writeItem` and `readItem` methods. Normally, a `C_XmlClassArrayField<T>` don't use any `std::*stream`.

Comment: The compiler error message is pretty clear. You need to overload `operator>>` for reading `Test` objects. Something like: `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Test& t);`.

Comment: I know and I understand this error, but, with the overload of `writeItem` and `readItem` in `C_XmlClassArrayField<T>`, I don't even use an `std::istream&`. This is my problem, and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Virtual member functions of a class template are instantiated as soon as the class template itself is instantiated, even if they are never called (this is in contrast with non-virtual members that are only instantiated when called). So virtual methods must be well-formed for any given class template arguments. Don't derive `C_XmlClassArrayField` from `C_XmlArrayField` - derive both from a common ancestor, preferably abstract.

Comment: It's what I done, but thanks it's useful to know this.